# POST https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken HTTP/1.1 results in Method Not Found on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using the LinkedIn Owin Middleare and started running into issues this morning and have now reproduced it to the below error:

```
POST https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: www.linkedin.com
Cookie: bscookie="v=1&201504071234373bc02b47-9d08-477f-8375-b80b281ef416AQEptFjv8jXPI93YmF-H-3kvnwSLwBF8"; bcookie="v=2&46f6f299-6702-48bf-8634-7ba023bd5099"; lidc="b=LB23:g=218:u=215:i=1428412320:t=1428487523:s=AQEQQq6vlEKPT3LW8c0cPEzRTKp-ToxL"
Content-Length: 267
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

grant_type=authorization_code&code=AQQRSgEH8vczSFJKNxtMpunzjYN6YJxoF2hiX_d9RVkqBvMC7TzRpur0p9NJFdQOUNf8RmFyj_cCg3ENTucRw5e-gQfEZ5sPGoujiFRsQ8Tb0pLnaog&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1729%2Fsignin-linkedin&client_id=&client_secret=
```

Results in method not found.

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Date: Tue, 07 Apr 2015 13:13:16 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 5487
X-Li-Fabric: PROD-ELA4
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0
Set-Cookie: lidc="b=LB23:g=218:u=215:i=1428412396:t=1428487523:s=AQExeP2uX-7KXQv79NIZmW0LB09uE4eJ"; Expires=Wed, 08 Apr 2015 10:05:23 GMT; domain=.linkedin.com; Path=/
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Connection: keep-alive
X-Li-Pop: PROD-IDB2
X-LI-UUID: 0FM/jIG90hPAzyhAqCsAAA==
```

Looking for anyone to confirm that there was a change on linkedin causing this error and that its not application specific.

Note that i removed teh above clientid/secrets.

Comment: I would also like to an answer to this question!

Comment: I am getting this same error and not using Owin.  Just building a WebRequest to https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken.  If I run the request in the Crome Extension "Advanced Rest Client" it works fine.  But hitting it through the c# end it fails with 405.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those using Owin Middleware and Owin.Security.Providers

A pre-release nuget was created with a fix.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin.Security.Providers/1.17.0-pre

This works for now. But until we know what linkedin has changed or comes with statement about what they changed people can use this as a hotfix.

Alittle more background on the fix can be found at : 
https://github.com/RockstarLabs/OwinOAuthProviders/issues/87#issuecomment-90838017

But the root cause is that LinkedIn changed something on there accessToken endpoint causing most of the libs using linkedin SSO had to apply a hotfix, but we yet haven't heard anything from linkedin.

Answer (score 2):

I also spent most of the morning off and on trying to get this to work.  Frustratingly it worked fine using [**Advanced Rest Client**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US&utm_source=ARC) chrome tool. A combination of this and fiddler showed the only difference in the header was that `Expect: 100-continue` flag in the header.  The only way I was able to get it to be set to false was in the web.config section

```
<system.net>
    <settings>
        <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This site has a great summary of the Expect: 100-continue header https://support.urbanairship.com/entries/59909909--Expect-100-Continue-Issues-and-Risks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue this morning too (I'm using DotNetOpenAuth). It looks like this is related to the use of the following request header: `Expect: 100-continue`

After removing this request header, the `HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed` response no longer occurs. Obviously this isn't much help if you don't have access to the source code!

I'm assuming this is due to a change in LinkedIn as I only started experiencing problems this morning. I'm guessing they'll need to look into a fix for this.

Comment: I was trying to remove this header in fiddler and got a 404 instead. Have you confirmed that removing this header solves the issue?

Comment: Looks to me that the header is set in the Owin Middleware anyway, so thats not possible to fix. Hoping linkedin is considering looking into this also.

Comment: Yes, removing the header sorts the issue out. I've just tried this in fiddler, the first time with the header specified which returned a 405 response. Then I ran the exact same request without the header and the request succeeded (access token was returned)

Comment: I get a 400 when removing the header.

Comment: does anyone have a curl example of a working request? I don't even have Expect: 100-continue in my current call.

Answer (score 0):

I started having this issue today.  After some research about Expect: 100-continue I found that putting 
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

in my Application_Start() function inside of Global.asax, takes out the 100-continue from the request and my login with LinkedIn is now working again.

Not a permanent fix as I would like to now why it broke in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue also use DotNetOpenAuth.

How I fix:

1. I remove from request header `"Expect: 100-continue"`
2. in my case `redirect_uri` was encoded and I remove encode for `redirect_uri` (for request to https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken )

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for curl, pretty simple:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:') );
```