# LinkedIn Authentication via Oauth2 returns null result (error=access_denied)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, asp.net-identity

I moved my ASP.NET MVC web application from membership to Identity authentication and since that I cannot authenticate on LinkedIn anymore.

The Facebook authentication is still working fine but the LinkedIn is always returning a null loginInfo after the GetExternalLoginInfo call.

For the LinkedIn I'm using the Owin LinkedIn provider: [LinkedIn APIs for .NET](https://github.com/tanveery/linkedin-net). I also unsuccessful tried to follow [this post from Jerrie Pelser](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/introducing-the-yahoo-linkedin-oauth-security-providers-for-owin).

The Application calls the ExternalLogin Action that executes the ExecuteResult method and calls back the ExternalLoginCallback (after I allow access to the application). As I stated before, the method AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() always returns a null loginInfo.

I checked the application settings in the LinkedIn and everything seems to be OK.

Ops! I almost forgot to say that the LinkedIn is returning back the URL with a generic error message: *"GET /Account/ExternalLoginCallback?error=access_denied HTTP/1.1"*

I can Authenticate using the DotNetOpenAuth.Clients (hosted github) but I'd like to just use the Identity.

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
var linkedInOptions = new LinkedInAuthenticationOptions();
        linkedInOptions.ClientId = "Xxxxx";
        linkedInOptions.ClientSecret = "Yyyyyyy";

        linkedInOptions.Scope.Add("r_fullprofile");

        linkedInOptions.Provider = new LinkedInAuthenticationProvider()
        {
            OnAuthenticated = async context =>
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("LinkedIn_AccessToken", context.AccessToken));
            }
        };

        linkedInOptions.SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie;

        app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(linkedInOptions);
```

**ExternalLogin**

```
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    }
```

**CallBack Action**

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
if (loginInfo == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

**LinkedIn CallBack URI**

```
http://localhost:3279/signin-linkedin
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some researches and a visit the NuGet package repository I found a [prerelease version of Owin.Security.Providers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin.Security.Providers/1.17.0-pre) that worked like a charm. I just had to install it from package manager console and the issue with the null return from the LinkedIn External Login has gone.

```
Install-Package Owin.Security.Providers -Pre
```

**Caution:** *Please be aware that the use of pre release packages may cause unexpected problems*.

Comment: omg you just saved me so much pain thank you. I can't believe you posted this answer just hours before I encountered it, it's like heavensent! Upgrading to 1.16 didnt fix it but upgrading again to 1.17 pre-release did the trick.

Comment: Here is the discussion behind the nuget prerelease package: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492598/post-https-www-linkedin-com-uas-oauth2-accesstoken-http-1-1-results-in-method/29509317#29509317

Comment: https://github.com/RockstarLabs/OwinOAuthProviders/issues/87#issuecomment-90838017