# LinkedIn API Suddenly Returning 405 Error

Tags: linkedin-api

One of our apps that uses LinkedIn Login, and has been working fine for a long time, is now suddenly broken, as of yesterday.  Most, but not all of our calls to the People endpoint return a 405 error.  Did something change for that endpoint?

I'm making a GET, just as the documentation says, and I'm getting back "(405) Method Not Allowed." from LinkedIn.  Here is the URL that I'm requesting:

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,email-address,first-name,last-name,headline,industry,summary,specialties,associations,honors,skills,interests,educations,phone-numbers,main-address,picture-url,public-profile-url,following,positions,three-current-positions,location,site-standard-profile-request)

Any help or any links to recent LinkedIn API changes would be appreciated.  I can't find any reference to any changes there in the last couple of days, but our app suddenly broke and we didn't change anything on our end.  Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LinkedIn made some unannounced changes yesterday which has broken their oAuth endpoint. They still haven't mentioned it of course.

You can see a workaround here:
[POST https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken HTTP/1.1 results in Method Not Found on LinkedIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492598/post-https-www-linkedin-com-uas-oauth2-accesstoken-http-1-1-results-in-method)

Comment: This solved it for me.  Just added that extra setting and all is back to normal.  Thanks a lot for the help.  LinkedIn, if you are listening, please announce all changes of this nature.

Comment: Maybe something to do with it: https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes

Answer (score 1):

We have solved this fix adding the request header "Expect" empty like this:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:') );

Comment: FWIW, my Stream Context implementation did not break from these API changes, only the cURL implementation.